# No certificate found alert in nodejs https server in mobile

Tags: tls, certificates, http, node.js

I have created a website using nodejs . And using ssl certificate from sslforfree.com . It is working fine on desktop and i checked it in SSL Checker it is working fine . But in mobile it is showing alert No certificates found. Please see the image attached.

[image]

here is my code

```
var app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 80;

var options = {
    key:fs.readFileSync('./ssl/private.key'),
    cert:fs.readFileSync('./ssl/certificate.crt'),  
    ca: [
        fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca_bundle.crt'),
    ],
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.secure) {
    return res.redirect(['https://', req.get('Host'), req.url].join(''));
  }
  next();
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/file', fileRoutes);
app.use('/task', taskRoutes);
app.use('/', mainRoutes);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Started up at port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is requesting a client certificate from the browser. If you did not intend to do that, why do you have `requestCert: true,`?